# Visual Studio 2015 - Generar diagramas UML de todo un proyecto MVC

Tags: visual-studio, mvc, uml

tengo un proyecto MVC5 en Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, queria saber si existe alguna manera de generar todo un proyecto de modelado UML para mi proyecto MVC, algo como dar clic derecho al proyecto MVC y generar proyecto de modelado UML, y de ahí que se genere un monton de diagramas que obviamente correspondan al proyecto mvc.

Comment: MVC es un patron de diseño que se implementa en la Capa de Presentación, el UML es un Lenguaje Unificado de Modelado el cual se usa para plasmar el mundo real en los diversos diagramas que trae. La manera de consevir un Software es conocer el core del negocio(conocer como piensa y opera el negocio), reconocer tus entidades de negocio, reglas de negocio, etc, después de eso recién puedes ver que arquitectura usar, que tecnología usar. ¿Cual es tu caso? ¿Estas heredando un sistema ya desarrollado, que apartir de la base de datos existente quieres obtener diagramas de UML?

Comment: Si es ese tu caso, podrías usar una herramienta case Power Designer y mediante ingeneria inversa podrías obtener el modelo http://www.tormentadebits.com/2012/08/powerdesigner-generar-modelo-fisico-ingenieria-inversa.html